# Gradle CLI command to print info about a specific task

Tags: gradle

I am trying to debug a gradle build (messing around with platforms, native builds and so on).

I would like to get a summary about a **specific** task `foo` inside my build using the gradle command line interface (build task for a native library spec).

I tried `gradle components` but since my build is getting rather large with many tasks, it is returning a lot of data.

To filter for a given task, I tried `gradle components foo`, but weirdly it still outputs all data rather than filtering for the given task.

Could not find any clear solution in the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html).

So basically, how can I display from the CLI information about a given task ?

EDIT : I am looking for toolchain and platform available for a given build task.

Answer (score 3):

When you run:

```
gradle tasks
```

It outputs a list of tasks and at the bottom it explains that if you want detailed help on a specific task you can run.

```
gradle help --task <task>
```

Comment: Note that you *may* need `gradle tasks --all` depending on how `foo` was created.

Comment: `gradle help --task <task>` doesn't returns as much information as components does. To debug the build or for inspection, I need at least tool chain and target platform. Basically, I would just need to filter the `components` command by just a task.